# What is the proper way to override is_a? and kind_of?

Tags: ruby

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i686-darwin10.5.0]

Am I missing something?

```
module Mixin
  def is_a?(o)
    return false if o == Hash
    super
  end
  alias_method :kind_of?, :is_a?
end

class Doc < Hash
  include Mixin
end

puts Doc.new().is_a?(Doc) # => true
puts Doc.new().kind_of?(Doc) # => super: no superclass method `is_a?'
```

Expected:

```
puts Doc.new().is_a?(Doc) # => true
puts Doc.new().kind_of?(Doc) # => true
puts Doc.new().is_a?(Hash) # => false
puts Doc.new().kind_of?(Hash) # => false
```

Everything is cool on rubinius and ruby 1.9.2p136

Comment: Perhaps it will hit me in a minute, but it would help if you would explain what you expected to see and point out the parts that differ from that. I don't see how your Mixin has any effect on the code you are testing, or how your custom `Doc2#is_a?` method makes any difference. You never pass a Hash in!

Comment: I do not get `# => super: no superclass method `is_a?'`; I get four `true` values printed with Ruby 1.9.2. What version of Ruby are you using? 1.8.7?

Comment: "Am I missing something?" Yes. Examples of what you get when you run it and what you wanted to receive instead.

Comment: You might consider using `respond_to?` to ask an object what it can do, rather than what kind of object it is.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone. This is a bug in 1.8.7 http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/734